# Trying to remove all rows without a numeric value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to remove all rows from a dataframe based on the condition that a column doesn't have a numeric value(int, float, etc..)

This is what I tried but it's not working...

```
city_df = city_df[city_df["city_latitude"].isnumeric()]
```

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Sample Data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a little tweak in the code:

```
city_df = city_df[city_df['city_latitude'].map(lambda x: str(x)).str.isnumeric().fillna(True)].dropna(subset=['city_latitude'])
```

Based on this data:

```
  city_latitude
0      36.35665
1     39.174503
2           NaN
3            AB
4            1C
5     35.961561
6     38.798958
```

The following result is obtained:

```
  city_latitude
0      36.35665
1     39.174503
5     35.961561
6     38.798958
```

EDIT:

Given your comments and errors I suggest a different approach:

```
city_df['city_latitude'] = pd.to_numeric(city_df['city_latitude'],errors='coerce')
city_df = city_df.dropna(subset=['city_latitude'])
```

Or in a single line:

```
city_df = city_df[~pd.to_numeric(city_df['city_latitude'],errors='coerce').isna()]
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the response, i just tried your solution but I recieve the error:  AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Could you please share some sample data in your question so I can have a more detailed look? As you can see with the sample data I created it works fine.

Comment: Ok i have just added some sample data in my question.  In the example above the row for Tecopa, CA should be dropped.

Comment: Please see the answer in the edit. If this helped you solve the issue, then consider upvoting and accepting it! Thanks!

Comment: Hello this works in this case but there are some other rows that have garbage charachters and letters so I want to remove all rows that are not numeric not just null.

Comment: Check the edit please, and future reference please try to provide all the relevant data needed for the question. Otherwise it feels like the problem hasn't been correctly explained.

Comment: I tried the combined solution but I am getting the original error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: See this last attempt :P

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
city_df=city_df[city_df['city_latitude'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [int, np.int64, float, np.float64])]
```

**or

following code will help you to understanding about the work flow**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
"city_latitude": [420, 380, 390,'a',5]

}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[df['city_latitude'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [int, np.int64, 
float, np.float64])]

print(df)
```

**output**:

```
  city_latitude
0           420
1           380
2           390
4             5
```